# How is ajax call enabled on magento ? are asynchronous calls backend config on magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, ajax

In a magento toolbar For example [in this site](http://magento-demo.lexiconn.com/accessories/jewelry.html?mode=grid) try changing the view from grid to list, this is a demo site and it occurs by reloading the page, but in [this premium theme](http://demo.magentech.com/themes/sm_g2shop/index.php/fashion/men-category.html?mode=list) toolbar when i toggle view (grid/list), sort or pagination from toolbar it occurs asynchronously.

I'm using this(premium) theme and i couldn't trace how it's getting asynchronously. How can i trace the function that is being called when the view is changed ?

I tried `console.log($('#sort_by li a').data('click'))` but his returns `undefined`

Comment: I see that all ajax links have `isLayerAjax=1` appended to them. Look for `isLayerAjax` in all the files an folders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you enable Chrome filtering of Eventhandlers you can see the click attachment being added by some inline script that is attaching handlers to the different classes defined in the toolbar:

```
function ajaxListener() {
    var els;
    els = $$('div.pager a').concat(
        $$('div.sorter a'),
        $$('div.pager select'),
        $$('div.sorter select'),
        $$('div.block-layered-nav a')
    );
    els.each(function(el) {
        if (el.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'a') {
            $(el).observe('click', function(event) {
                handleEvent(this, event);
            });
        } else if (el.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'select') {
            $(el).setAttribute('onchange', '');
            $(el).observe('change', function(event) {
                handleEvent(this, event);
            });
        }
    });
```